# getElementsByTagName() behaves differently in IE and FF

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, gwt, browser

I am new to JavaScript, trying to figure out a  tag information value. GWT Code is as follows..

```
public static native boolean isToolBarInstalled() /*-{
    alert("Validating the toolbar installed.");
    var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].getElementsByTagName('meta');
        var i;
        alert ("Meta length: "+metas.length);
        for (i = 0; i < metas.length; i++){
            alert("Value: "+metas[i].value);
            if (metas[i].getAttribute('name') == "toolbar"){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
        }-*/;
```

FF return true whereas IE returns false, for the same page? Any clue/suggestions would be helpful.

WM.

HTML is too huge to post, here is a snippet of the code..

```
<html>
<head>
    ....
    <title>My App</title>
    <meta name="toolbar" content="1.0">
</head>
<body>
.....
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me in IE7.

Check you haven't got any text content before the `<meta>` end-tag other than simple whitespace.

If you have any non-whitespace text in or before `<html>` or `<head>`, the browser will decide that you meant to open the `<body>` to contain the text. (This is actually valid in non-XHTML HTML, as the `</head>` end-tag and the `<body>` start-tag are optional.) That means closing the `<head>` section, so the number of `<meta>` tags inside `<head>` will be 0.

In any case you might as well say just:

```
var metas= document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
```

as the bit about checking they're in `<head>` is redundant for a valid document; that's the only place `<meta>` is allowed to appear.

```
        alert("Value: "+metas[i].value);
```

There's no `.value` on `<meta>`, do you mean `.content`?

```
        if (metas[i].getAttribute('name') == "toolbar"){
```

Use `metas[i].name`. There's no reason to use `getAttribute`/`setAttribute` on an HTML document and there are problems with it on IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
element.attributes[value].nodeAttribute;
```

[As explained here](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2007/03/getAttributefor_is_always_null_in_Internet_Explore.html):

> The getAttribute() method will return
>   "null" in Internet Explorer when
>   trying to get the for attribute of a
>   label element.

Might be the same issue...

Well look:

- [Example](http://jsbin.com/ihisu5)
- [Source](http://jsbin.com/ihisu5/edit)

In this example it is working on IE.

```
function isToolBarInstalled() {
    alert("Validating the toolbar installed.");
    var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].getElementsByTagName('meta');
    var i;
    alert ("Meta length: "+metas.length);
    for (i = 0; i < metas.length; i++){
        alert("Value: "+metas[i].value);

        var attr = metas[i].getAttribute('name');

        // IE workaround
        if (attr == null)
        {
            attr = metas[i].attributes["name"];
            if (attr != null) attr = attr.nodeValue;
        }

        if (attr == "toolbar")
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

alert( "Is installed: " + isToolBarInstalled() );
```

Comment: Not really, the code doesn't reach getAttribute(). The line - alert ("Meta length: "+metas.length); prints 0 and the 'for' loop never gets executed.

Comment: @Win: Maybe it's a wrong (not closed) tag? On the example it is working. Maybe it's something on your HTML.